# How to display an icon in Odoo ListView?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, listview, treeview, odoo-8

I want to show a Warning icon in Odoo tree view if score <= avg

```
    <field name="score"/>
    <field name="avg"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And don't know if it the best way, but I used a `button` tag to show the icon in the TreeView

```
    <button readonly="True" class="oe_inline oe_stat_button" icon="STOCK_DIALOG_WARNING" attrs="{'invisible': [('score_lt_avg', '=', False)]}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Python code (add the field `score_lt_avg` to the model which has `score` and `avg` fields):

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('score', 'avg')
def _compute_score_lt_avg(self):
    for record in self:
        record.score_lt_avg = (record.score <= record.avg)

score_lt_avg = fields.Boolean(
    compute='_compute_acore_lt_avg',
    string='Score equal to/lower than average',
)
```

Your XML code (you must add `score`, `avg` and `score_lt_avg` to the form view, not only to the tree view, otherwise the computed field will not work):

```
<field name="score"/>
<field name="avg"/>
<field name="score_lt_avg" invisible="1"/>
<span class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" attrs="{'invisible': [('score_lt_avg', '=', False)]}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, It works the form view, but I want to show the icon in the TreeView. Do you know how?